# IDictionary<string, string> into string[,] by LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm having some legacy code that recieves a `string[,]` as one of the method arguments.

However, in my method I recieve a `IDictionary<string, string>` that I have to convert to a `string[,]` to proceed.

I've created the code like that,

```
var names = attachments.Keys.ToArray();
var paths = attachments.Values.ToArray();

var multipleAttachments = new string[2,attachments.Count];
for(var i = 0; i < attachments.Count; i++)
{
  multipleAttachments[0, i] = names[i];
  multipleAttachments[1, i] = paths[i];
}
```

I'm not really happy with it and I am looking for some way to use a LINQ expression for the convertion. Is that possible?

Comment: would like to see the method signature please this is only a fragment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ isn't particularly good when it comes to rectangular arrays. You can *easily* create a jagged array:

```
// Note that this ends up "rotated" compared with the rectangular array
// in your question.
var array = attachments.Select(pair => new[] { pair.Key, pair.Value })
                       .ToArray();
```

... but there's no equivalent for rectangular arrays. If you *have* to use a rectangular array, you might want to consider creating an extension method to perform the conversion for you. If you *only* want it for this case, you're probably best off sticking with what you've got... or possibly:

```
var multipleAttachments = new string[2, attachments.Count];
int index = 0;
foreach (var pair in multipleAttachments)
{
    multipleAttachments[0, index] = pair.Key;
    multipleAttachments[1, index] = pair.Value;
    index++;
}
```

That will avoid creating the extra arrays, and will also not rely on `Keys` and `Values` supplying their entries in the same order.

Comment: The result of that expression is string[][], isn't it ?

Comment: @alexanderb: Yes, a jagged array, as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var multipleAttachments = new string[2, attachments.Count];

            int i = 0;
            attachments.ToList().ForEach(p =>
                {
                    multipleAttachments[0, i] = p.Key;
                    multipleAttachments[1, i] = p.Value;
                    i++;
                });
```